# Delete Item in RecyclerView and Dao with buttonclick

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView displaying data from a Dao.
In the data that is shown in the recyclerView is a button with which the item should get deleted.

I know the function for that is :

```
fun deleteReceipt(receipts: Receipts) = viewModelScope.launch {
    receiptDao.delete(receipts)
}
```

But I am not quite sure where to put it and call it. Because if I want to call it in the Adapter where i set the other displayed Item values I have no access to the Dao

Here is the fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HistoryFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_history) {

private val viewModel: PurchaseViewmodel by viewModels()




override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val binding = FragmentHistoryBinding.bind(view)

    val exampleAdapter = ExampleAdapter()

    binding.apply{
        recyclerView.apply{

            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            adapter = exampleAdapter
            setHasFixedSize(true)
        }
    }

    setFragmentResultListener("add_receipt_request"){_,bundle ->
        val result = bundle.getInt("add_receipt_request")
        viewModel.onAddResult(result)
    }

    viewModel.receipts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ /// New Items get passed to the List
        exampleAdapter.submitList(it)
    }
}
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PurchaseViewmodel @Inject constructor(
private val receiptDao: ReceiptDao
    ): ViewModel() {
private val tasksEventChannel = Channel<TasksEvent>()
val addTaskEvent = tasksEventChannel.receiveAsFlow()
        val receipts = receiptDao.getAllReceipts().asLiveData()

fun onAddResult(result: Int){
    when (result){
        ADD_RECEIPT_RESULT_OK ->showReceiptSavedConfirmation("Receipt is saved")
    }
}
private fun showReceiptSavedConfirmation (text: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    tasksEventChannel.send(TasksEvent.ShowReceiptSavedConfirmation(text))
}

fun deleteReceipt(receipts: Receipts) = viewModelScope.launch {
    receiptDao.delete(receipts)
}

sealed class TasksEvent {
    data class ShowReceiptSavedConfirmation(val msg: String) : TasksEvent()
}
}
```

And the Adapter:

```
class ExampleAdapter : ListAdapter<Receipts,ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder { // Basically how to get a new Item from the List and display it
    val binding = ReceiptsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
    return ExampleViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(currentItem)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return super.getItemCount()
}

class ExampleViewHolder(private val binding: ReceiptsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){ //Examples One Row in our list
    fun bind (receipts: Receipts) {
        binding.apply {
            storeHistory.text = receipts.store
            amountHistory.text = receipts.total
            dateHistory.text  = receipts.date
        }
    }
}
class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Receipts>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Receipts, newItem: Receipts) =
        oldItem.id == newItem.id

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Receipts, newItem: Receipts) =
        oldItem == newItem
}
}
```

Comment: let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

- Create a listener using Interface
- Implement the listener in Fragment
- Create listener variable in Adapter
- pass the listener from fragment to adapter
- pass the listener to viewHolder
- on Delete button click of that item call the listener method, which will trigger the implementation in Fragment where you have access to your ViewModel
- delete the receipt using `viewModel.deleteReceipt`

Comment: let me know if you need anything else